# How can you have two different running clocks in ExtJS Version 5?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, clock, seconds

I'm a relatively new [sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) user but I've been using Version 5 for a little over a month now.  Getting pretty good at it but I have a dilemma hopefully SOMEONE has gone through before and has an answer to.

Here's the deal.  I have an application where I would like to have two different active running clocks (ones that update automatically every second) on the page.  I can get one clock on the page but the second active clock will NOT show.  Here's what I have so far in my view controller:

```
onUpdateCurrentTime : function () {

    var me = this;

    task = {
        run: function() {
            clock.setValue("Current Date: " + Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'F j, Y, g:i:s A'));
        },
        interval: 1000,
    };
    Ext.TaskManager.start(task);

    clock = me.lookupReference("currentTime");
        clock.setValue(task);
},

onUpdateCurrentDate : function () {

    var me = this;

    var task = {
        run: function() {
            clock.setValue("Date: " + Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'F j, Y g:i:s A'));
        },
        interval: 1000,
    };
    var runner = new Ext.util.TaskRunner();
    runner.start(task);

    var clock = me.lookupReference("currentDate");
        clock.setValue(task);
}
});
```

If you notice under the `updateCurrentDate` function I am using a slightly different but effective variable 'runner' to differentiate between the two but it doesn't work.  Also tried it using the same wording in each function (since the variables are local) but no dice.  Is there anyone out there who knows how I can have two different active clocks on the page?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. I would suggest you put together a fiddle (http://fiddle.sencha.com).

Comment: *"I'm a relatively new sencha-touch user but I've been using Version 5 for a little over a month now"*. The latest Sencha Touch version at the moment is 2.4.2. Please be certain about *what* you are using — Sencha Touch or Ext JS.